# Text.ParserCombinators

Tags: haskell

I want to make a parser combinator for regular expressions in  Haskell. So I defined my own data type and made a match function for this type. I recently discovered about Text.ParserCombinators. If I use `parseTest` function the result type is `IO`. So how do I use Text.ParserCombinators to return the type of my created data? Below is my code.

```
data Reg = Eps
        |Sym Char --caracter
        |Alt Reg Reg --a sau b a|b
        |Seq Reg Reg -- secventa ab  sau chiar paranteza
        |Rep (Int, Maybe Int) Reg   --Star repet on or more time
        |Dif Reg    --not
deriving (Show)
--match function
accept :: Reg -> String ->Bool

accept ( parse term "abcd") "abcd"
ERROR - Type error in application
*** Expression     : accept (parse term "abcd") "abcd"
*** Term           : parse term "abcd"
*** Type           : [Char] -> Either ParseError Reg
*** Does not match : Reg
--term is the Parser function where the grammars is defined
term :: Parser Reg
term = buildExpressionParser ops atom where
```

Comment: Parsec's expression parser builds a table for parsing for "expressions" in the sense of arithmetic expressions e.g. "1 + 2" etc and expressions (rather than statements) in programming languages. Aren't all regexp operators postfix? If so you'd be better off using another technique.

Comment: Actually `alt` for regexp is infix of course. You might still find using the builtin expression parser is not as easy as doing it yourself for this problem though.

Comment: `parse` requires additional parameter - name of a source file. You can give it `""` if you do not care. It will give you back `Either ParseError Reg`, and you can pattern match on Left/Right then.

Answer (score 1):

As sdcvvc notes in the comments, `parse` isn't applied to enough arguments.